# Do players in Animal Crossing: New Horizons count towards the villager total?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Guides say our island can have 10 villagers. We have 4 players on the island, can we still have 10 villagers? Or will we be limited to 6?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Player residents do not count towards the 10 villager max. You can have 10 npc villagers on top of the number of player villagers you have occupying the island.

Sources:

- https://gamerant.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-how-many-villagers-can-you-have-limit-max/
- personal experience (10 villagers + 3 players from my household).